# SIM card using an external 3G modem while traveling in Israel

Tags: israel, internet

Will I be able to buy a SIM card in Israel for use with my modem when I'll be traveling there? Where to buy it and how much will it cost?

Answer (score 6):

The SIM is free, but you have to buy a service package. I looked up on Orange site, they charge 119 shekels for a 10GB package for private people (99 for businesses), and 4 shekels/1MB for prepaid plans.

$1 = 3.75 shekels, and there's a VAT charge of 16% on top of the price.

In addition to Orange, there are two other major providers - Cellcom and Pelephone. All or some of them usually have points of sale in any mall. The prices vary between the providers, but are more or less comparable.

Comment: Hi, Oana, welcome to Travel.SE, if you found this answer useful and it truly answered your question, please mark it as a correct one by clicking a "tick/check mark" to the left of it.